# Change toolbar from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I am writing an app using [jetpack recommended architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide), [NavigationUI, and the navigation graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation). So I have one main activity with a `Toolbar`, a `BottomNavigationView` and  the `NavHostFragment`.

Everything worked nicely until now: I need to change the `Toolbar` to use a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and hide the `BottomNavigationView` in one of my fragment.

I tried to add a navigation listener (as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events)) to hide my `Toolbar` and `BottomNavigationView`, and in my fragment, I inflate the new `Toolbar` and call `setSupportActionBar()` on the main activity.

```
// in MainActivity.java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // ...
  navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
        if(destination.getId() == R.id.detailFragment){
          bottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          topBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
          bottomBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          topBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
      });
  // ...
}

public void changeToolbar(Toolbar toolbar){
  getSupportActionBar().hide();
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

// in DetailFragment.java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // ...
  navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);

  AppBarConfiguration.Builder builder = new Builder(
      R.id.accuracyFragment,
      R.id.dataFragment,
      R.id.magnetFragment,
      R.id.settingsFragment);
  AppBarConfiguration config = builder.build();
  NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbarLayout, toolbar, navController);
  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeToolbar(toolbar);
  // ...
}
```

It almost works correctly, but:

1. when I navigate up or go to another fragment, the `BottomNavigationView` is not correctly displayed. It seems to be pushed down by the `Toolbar`.
2. the transition is ugly: the toolbar is visibly changing, I can see it disappearing before being changed

So the question is: is there another way to change/hide the navigation elements from the fragment? If not, should I create a new activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a wild ride, but I finally found a solution. For the issue number 1, this is due to the way Android manages the `fitsSystemWindows` property propagation. For this to work correctly, I made a few changes to my layouts. I created a custom `FitSystemWindowLinearLayout`, which is simply a class extending the standard `LinearLayout` and overriding `onApplyWindowInsets` like this:

```
  @Override
  public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int index = 0; index < childCount; ++index) {
      getChildAt(index).dispatchApplyWindowInsets(insets);
    }

    return insets;
  }
```

My main activity now looks like this:

```
+-- CoordinatorLayout, fitsSystemWindows=false
    +-- FitSystemWindowLinearLayout, fitsSystemWindows="false"
        +-- Toolbar
        +-- NavHostFragment, fitsSystemWindows="false"
        +-- BottomNavigationView, fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

For the second issue, namely the transition being ugly, I mitigated that by adding a shared element to the transition.

All in all, I think it's easier to use a new activity for this kind of things, the NavigationUI falls a bit short for now.

Here are some resources that helped me:

- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec
- [Android fitsSystemWindows not working when replacing fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307674/android-fitssystemwindows-not-working-when-replacing-fragments)
- [Collapsing Toolbar problems with Status Bar and Bottom Bar. Fitssystemwindows="true" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714241/collapsing-toolbar-problems-with-status-bar-and-bottom-bar-fitssystemwindows-t)
- [fitsSystemWindows effect gone for fragments added via FragmentTransaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190612/fitssystemwindows-effect-gone-for-fragments-added-via-fragmenttransaction/34345286#34345286)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/aryxvu/fitssystemwindows_misbehaves_with_navigation/
  -https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec